# Babylon load 3D model

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I have a problem, I can't load a 3d model  with the expansion .glb in Babylon.
I make the instruction to load it but it load only the scene with out the model.
but if I create a box or another thing it appear normally in the scene.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To load a file of a given type, Babylon must first have a reference to the plugin for that file type.

If you are using npm, you can use install loaders from this link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babylonjs/loaders

And use gltf loader, specify the import as following:
import "@babylonjs/loaders/glTF";